# How output file to browser with php?

Tags: php, curl

I have managed to find, retrieve and save a file using CURL. Now I want to output file to browser with php.

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://example.com/downloadshort/5941';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);

// show header on the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);

// get size of header
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
// take header part from response
$header = substr($data, 0, $header_size);
// delete header part from data variable
$data   = substr($data, $header_size+1);

$error = curl_error($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);

// get file name and extension from header
preg_match('~filename=(.*)\.([\S]+)~i', $header, $f);
list($dummy, $filename, $ext)       = $f;


$destination = $filename.'.'.$ext;


?>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What kind of file?

Comment: @JayBlanchard any file (can be .zip; .exe or rar)

Comment: You cannot output any of those file types to the browser. Are you talking about making the file available for download?

Comment: Why not actually add a complete explanation of what you're trying to do in the question instead of repeating "Thanks for help." (which shouldn't be there anyway) to circumvent the question quality filter?

Answer (score 2):

Considering you said .zip, .exe, etc, I assume you want to be able to show the file regardless, which means ability to download it.. if so:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filepath);
```

Comment: @IncredibleHat What assumption? His first line said: "I have managed to find, retrieve and save a file using CURL." ... SAVE a file.

Comment: Just like you assumed I assumed he was saving a file?

Comment: There was no assumption, there was inference from the situational context he provided. I gave a solution, if he can't figure out `$filepath` and how to use the variable correctly, I think he has more issues that not using `destination`. This isn't a teaching site.

Comment: Geezus, whatever dude. Get off it.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have the data you want to send to the browser, just `print` or `echo` it.

```
echo $data;
```

To get the browser to display the download box, you need to set the correct header ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to the browser.
The documentation includes an example of how to do this:"

> Example #1 Download dialog
>
> If you want the user to be prompted to save the data you are sending,
> such as a generated PDF file, you can use the » Content-Disposition
> header to supply a recommended filename and force the browser to
> display the save dialog.
>
> ```php
> <?php
> // We'll be outputting a PDF
> header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
>
> // It will be called downloaded.pdf
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
>
> // The PDF source is in original.pdf
> readfile('original.pdf');
> ?>
> ```

In your case, after setting up the correct header, you should replace `readfile('original.pdf')`; with `print $data;`.

In your code, you have a `$ext` variable for the file, but the `Content-Type` header needs to be more specific. You can refer to [Media_type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) for guidance.

Comment: Instead of a generic copy paste quote, how bout you actually edit the code you have there to match his variables and data?

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer, thank you!